# Include archived CRAN package in package

Tags: r, cran

I'm creating an R package, and I would like to rely on the [falsy](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/falsy) package, which has recently been [archived](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/falsy/index.html) from CRAN.

With a non-archived package, one would typically add the name of the package to the `Imports` list in the `DESCRIPTION` file. How does one import a package that's been archived by CRAN?

Note: After contacting Gábor it seems the reason falsy is archived is due to potentially dangerous [inconsistencies](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/falsy#warnings) between native and `falsy` notions of falsehood. He does not plan to unarchive the package.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32533483/324364) might be the answer you're looking for...?

Comment: That's definitely A solution, though an ideal solution wouldn't require any action on the part of the end user.

Comment: The comments on that question also discuss the option of creating your own **drat** repo on github, which might be more work for you, but probably less for users.

Comment: I see two options: 1) copy the source code for the functions you need from `falsy` into your own package.  Then provide proper attribution to the author of those functions. 2) Send a request to CRAN to become the package maintainer for `falsy`, fix the check problems, and resubmit it to CRAN.

Comment: Re 2) It appears that falsy has already been patched to pass tests: https://github.com/gaborcsardi/falsy/commit/ee26873d99255560cfad60be2812cea4437d20e1 . It's getting 0 errors/warnings/notes from check() on my machine with  R 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
FALSY <- FALSE

TRUTHY <- TRUE

is_falsy <- function(object) {
  is.null(object) ||
    identical(object, FALSE) ||
    identical(object, 0L) ||
    identical(object, 0.0) ||
    identical(object, 0+0i) ||
    identical(object, "") ||
    identical(object, as.raw(0)) ||
    identical(object, logical()) ||
    identical(object, integer()) ||
    identical(object, double()) ||
    identical(object, complex()) ||
    identical(object, character()) ||
    identical(object, raw()) ||
    identical(object, list()) ||
    inherits(object, "try-error")
}

is_truthy <- function(object) {
  ! is_falsy(object)
}

`%&&%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  lres <- withVisible(eval(lhs, envir = parent.frame()))
  if (is_truthy(lres$value)) {
    eval(rhs, envir = parent.frame())
  } else {
    if (lres$visible) { lres$value } else { invisible(lres$value) }
  }
}

nay <- function(rhs) {
  if (is_falsy(rhs)) { TRUTHY } else { FALSY }
}

try_quietly <- function(expr) {
  try(expr, silent = TRUE)
}
```

is the *entire extent* (minus roxygen comments) of the package. Why not just include it in your package?

Failing that, possibly ask Gabor if he's planning re-releasing it to CRAN or if you could take over maintenance?

Comment: I've contacted Gabor, waiting on a reply. I'm hesitant to copy the source directly because I believe code duplication is inherently bad.

Comment: It's **significantly** better than relying on an archived package.

Comment: Interesting. What are your reasons for saying that?

Comment: Because the average R user will have no idea how to install it and it got archived for a reason (usually due to it failing CRAN checks). Why would you rely on something like that? Seems crazy to me and pretty disrespectful of your potential user base.