# Make CRAN R package suggest GitHub R package

Tags: r, github, cran

I want to use the R package `BOLTSSIRR` available on GitHub in my R package, which I want to upload to CRAN.

I listed `BOLTSSIRR` under `Suggests:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file and made the link to GitHub available using `Additional_repositories: https://github.com/daviddaigithub/BOLTSSIRR`.

However, running `R CMD check --as-cran` I get:

```
Suggests or Enhances not in mainstream repositories:
  BOLTSSIRR
Availability using Additional_repositories specification:
  BOLTSSIRR   no   ?                                          
  ?            ?   https://github.com/daviddaigithub/BOLTSSIRR
Additional repositories with no packages:
  https://github.com/daviddaigithub/BOLTSSIRR
```

So the GitHub link does not seem to get recognized in the check. Might I have to change something here?

Comment: It's been answered over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493388/create-an-r-package-that-depends-on-another-r-package-located-on-github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an R package that depends on another R package located on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493388/create-an-r-package-that-depends-on-another-r-package-located-on-github)

Comment: @WiktorGustafsson @Oliver Thank you. Unfortunately, this does not seem to answer my question yet. The ```Remotes:``` field does not seem to get recognized in the check. I get:
"* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... WARNING

Unknown, possibly mis-spelled, fields in DESCRIPTION:
  'Remotes'

Strong dependencies not in mainstream repositories:
  BOLTSSIRR".   Note that in the case of the other question, both packages were on GitHub, whereas my package needs to be uploaded to CRAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you found, you can't use `Remotes` in a CRAN package.  What you need to do is to make sure the `.tar.gz` file for the package you are depending on is available somewhere.  Github doesn't do that automatically, because `https://github.com/daviddaigithub/BOLTSSIRR` isn't set up as a package repository.

The solution is to create your own small repository, and keep copies of non-CRAN packages there.  The `drat` package (available here: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) makes this easy as long as you have a Github account:  follow the instructions here:  https://github.com/drat-base/drat.  In summary:

1. Fork https://github.com/drat-base/drat into your account, and clone it to your own computer.
2. Enable Github Pages with the `docs/` folder in the main branch.
3. Install the `drat` package into R using `remotes::install_github("eddelbuettel/drat")`.  (I assume this version will make it to CRAN eventually; if you use the current CRAN version instructions are slightly more complicated.)
4. Build the package you want to insert.  You need the source version; you might want binaries too, if those are hard for your users to build.
5. Run `options(dratBranch="docs"); drat::insertPackage(...)` to insert those files into your repository.
6. Commit the changes, and push them to Github.
7. In the package that needs to use this non-CRAN package, add
   `Additional_repositories:  https://yourname.github.io/drat`
   to the DESCRIPTION.

**You** will be responsible for updating your repository if `BOLTSSIRR` is updated.  This is good because the updates might break yours:  after all, it's still in development mode.  It's also bad because your users won't automatically get bug fixes.

That's it, if I haven't missed anything!

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate helpful answer! Currently I have an issue in step 5: I tried: `drat::insertPackage(file="pathtofile/BOLTSSIRR_0.1.0.tar.gz")` and got `Error: Directory ~/git/drat not found`. I guess, I have to specify the argument `repodir `. Unfortunately, I'm not very familar with GitHub. So I don't understand the help page regarding `repodir`. What should I use for `repodir`?

Comment: I managed to upload the package, but I get: "* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ...Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Suggests or Enhances not in mainstream repositories:
  BOLTSSIRR
Availability using Additional_repositories specification:
  BOLTSSIRR   no   ?
  ?            ?   https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat
Additional repositories with no packages:
  https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat" What could be the problem here?

Comment: I think you haven't pushed things to Github.  I'd expect to find the repository at RomanHornung.github.io/drat (step 2 should have created this), but don't see anything there; in the source location, github.com/RomanHornung/drat, I see a repos but it doesn't have BOLTSSIRR in it.  (That should have happened after step 5, but maybe you need an explicit push to Github that I didn't ask for.)

Comment: Thank you again! I tried again and after `insertPackage(file="path1/BOLTSSIRR_0.1.0.tar.gz", repodir="path2/romanhornung.github.io")`, it was in my local repo. Then I wrote `git add --all`, `git commit -m "Second commit"`, and `git push -u origin master`. This pushed the changes to `RomanHornung/romanhornung.github.io`, but they are not visible on `https://romanhornung.github.io` and `romanhornung.github.io/drat` still does not exist (or it has no content) even though it says "Your site is published at https://romanhornung.github.io/drat/" on the "RomanHornung/drat" page. What could be wrong?

Comment: I'd expect to see it in https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat/tree/master/docs/src/contrib, but it's not there.  On your home system, that's `docs/src/contrib` of your fork of the `drat-base` repository.  You need to tell Github to publish from there; I forget the details of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks again! I now got it to working: Before step 5 I cloned the drat repository to my local computer using `git clone https://github.com/RomanHornung/drat` and then deleted the files in the folders `docs/src/contrib` and `docs/bin/windows/contrib/4.0`. Also before step 5 `options(dratBranch="docs")` was necessary. After step 5, being in the `drat` directory on my computer I wrote: 1) `git add .`, 2) `git commit -m "Added package"`, 3) `git push origin master`. I executed the git commands from the Terminal in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330, I know it's a somewhat stale thread, but it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Answering since I cant comment.  @user2554330 answer is correct, and will fix the additional package not being available.  However, you may still get a NOTE about:

> Package suggested but not available for checking: <yourpackage>

which you should be able to explain is a result of the drat-hosted library, but the package will not be available for e.g. vignettes/examples in checks.  This note in [CRAN policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) still applies:

> A package listed in ‘Suggests’ or ‘Enhances’ should be used conditionally in examples or tests if it cannot straightforwardly be installed on the major R platforms. (‘Writing R Extensions’ recommends that they are always used conditionally.)

In my submission I was getting errors in examples due to not being able to find a package hosted in a drat repo that was listed in `Additional_repositories`.  One way around this is to use `@examplesIf requireNamespace("yourpackage", quietly = TRUE)` instead of `@examples` in roxygen comments or conditionally run stuff in vignettes with

```
if (requireNamespace("yourpackage", quietly = TRUE)) {
  result = yourpackage::function()
  # ...
}
```