# Import R package from Github when developing R package

Tags: r, package

I am trying to develop my own R package, which relies on the R package enrichR (from wjawaid/enrichR). This package is available on both CRAN and Github, but due to a bug in their CRAN version, I want to exclusively use their Github package (v2.1). I've followed
[Create an R package that depends on another R package located on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493388/create-an-r-package-that-depends-on-another-r-package-located-on-github) to try and adjust my DESCRIPTION so that I don't get that bug, but it hasn't been working so far. This is what I've tried:

```
Imports: enrichR (>= 2.1)
Remotes: wjawaid/enrichR
```

How would I be able to import the Github version of enrichR specifically into my package? I'm not having issues when I use enrichR outside of this package.

Comment: Is your goal to upload to CRAN or just keep it on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have is sufficient as long as you use `remotes::install_local` or `remotes::install_github` or similar to install your package.  If you are using the basic `install.packages` or `R CMD INSTALL` to install it, you need to put a copy of `enrichR` 2.1 in a CRAN-style repository, and refer to that repository in an `Additional_repositories` field in your `DESCRIPTION` file.  This is easier than it sounds, using `drat`:  see https://github.com/drat-base/drat .