# R package - force a dependency on a GitHub version over a CRAN version

Tags: r, shiny, r-package

There is an R package called `firebase` that I am trying to declare as a dependency for my Shiny application built as a package. If I structure my DESCRIPTION file like:

```
Imports:
firebase
```

This will make the end user who installs my package download and install the CRAN version of `firebase`. However, I want to force a dependency on the `master` branch of `www.github.com/JohnCoene/firebase`.

Do I simply remove the `Imports` and replace it with:

```
Remotes:
JohnCoene/firebase
```

Or do I need both:

```
Imports:
firebase

Remotes:
JohnCoene/firebase
```

Comment: I think you need both, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32533483/11598948)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need both.

Imports tells what to import and remote specifies where to find it.